# Set eslint rule for unused class methods in React component

Tags: reactjs, eslint, es6-class

I am trying to set an eslint rule for methods in class that are never used. Like in the following react component I have a method `unUsedMethod` which is never used, but eslint does not show an error for it.

```
class Sample extends Component {
    unUsedMethod() {
        console.log('I am never used');
    }
    render() {
        return 'Hello!';
    }
}
```

My eslint file looks like this

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true,
            "sourceType": "module",
            "allowImportExportEverywhere": false,
            "codeFrame": false
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [2, 4, {"SwitchCase": 1, "ObjectExpression": "first"}],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ],
        "react/display-name": 0,
        "react/prop-types": 0, // Temporary
        "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
        "no-trailing-spaces": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess eslint check only variables that are not used, It not check for class methods.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-unused-react-component-methods might work. youll have to run `npm install eslint-plugin-no-unused-react-component-methods` to enable it apparently

Comment: I tried the eslint-plugin-no-unused-react-component-methods, but I didn't get it to work. Has anyone else got it to work?

Comment: @Waltari No. But if you start using React Hooks and move away from class based components to functional components. This issue becomes obsolete.

Comment: That is true, but we have a significant codebase in react components. I got the plugin got work and removed a few functions with it. Doesn't work for static functions which is a shame, so I won't be having it on all the time.

Comment: @Waltari How did you get the plugin to work?

Comment: Sorry for not doing it earlier. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin does what you are asking for. However a word of caution.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-unused-react-component-methods

Currently it is impossible to simply have a parser that would check for unused component properties, because component properties can be called dynamically.

For example:

```
class Sample extends Component {
    // Plugin falsely flags this as unused.
    unUsedMethod() {
        console.log('I am used dynamically');
    }
    render() {
        // No way to parse dynamic function calls reliably
        this['unUsedMethod']();
        return 'Hello!';
    }
}
```

It also wouldn't work with react-onclickoutside package, as it requires a function to be attached to the component, that is called by wrapping the component in a HOC. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickoutside

**Still the plugin helped me find a few unused functions, so it is worth a try in my opinion.**

First install the package: `npm i eslint-plugin-no-unused-react-component-methods --save-dev`

Add "no-unused-react-component-methods" to your eslint configuration in the plugins section:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "no-unused-react-component-methods"
    ],
}
```

And add into the rules section

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-react-component-methods/no-unused-react-component-methods": 2,
    }
}
```

So your config would look like:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "allowImportExportEverywhere": false,
      "codeFrame": false
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "no-unused-react-component-methods"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-react-component-methods/no-unused-react-component-methods": 2,
    "indent": [2, 4, { "SwitchCase": 1, "ObjectExpression": "first" }],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "react/display-name": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0, // Temporary
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
    "no-trailing-spaces": 1
  }
}
```

Now it should highlight any seemingly unused functions! Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Awesome! It works now. I was missing the correct rule text. Thanks.