# Eslint - what rule is responses for highlighting wrong/undefined methods in React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I saw this post [Set eslint rule for unused class methods in React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584642/set-eslint-rule-for-unused-class-methods-in-react-component) where said, that this is impossible without third party packages. But maybe is there some way to enable highlighting throw native eslint environment or some VS Code plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such rule. Only thing that you can do - it to check the ordering of your app methods with React life-Cycle methods, in way like:

```
 /// ...some code

   _setInitialState =() => { // error: [eslint] _setInitialState should be placed after componentDidMount

     ... some logic
   }

    componentDidMount() {
     ...some logic
   }

 /// ..some code
```

To make this work you would need to install locally in project the next package from npm: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/sort-comp.md#rule-options